# How to work around Scala type erasure when reflectively processing Java objects?

Tags: java, scala, type-erasure

I have a legacy mixed Scala/Java project. It has a custom home-brew ORM mapping tool that generates a bunch of Java entity classes and then works with them in Scala, mapping them from/to custom property maps and yaml files.

Today I stumbled upon an issue that the ORM tool converts all strings inside of `List<String>` to maps of `Array[Byte]` (which leads to further conversion of data into java.io.ByteArrayInputStream instead of simple Scala list of Strings).

While attempting to fix the issue and add `List[String]` to the ORM field value matcher, I got bit by type erasure. Unfortunately, I have no control over the Java classes generated by the automatic tool, so I cannot use TypeTags etc.; reflection seems to be my only hope.

Here is a simplified example of the problematic use case.

Java entities:

```
public class SubEntity {
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Entity {

    protected List<SubEntity> field1;
    protected List<String> field2;

    public List<SubEntity> getField1() {
        if (field1 == null) {
            field1 = new ArrayList<SubEntity>();
        }
        return this.field1;
    }

    public List<String> getField2() {
        if (field2 == null) {
            field2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.field2;
    }
}
```

The piece of problematic Scala code:

```
val ent = new Entity
  ent.getClass.getMethods
    .filter (m => m.getName.startsWith("get") && m.getName != "getClass")
    .filter (m => m.getParameterTypes.size == 0)
    .foreach (m => m.invoke(ent) match {
      case null => null
      // Not able to differentiate between List[String] and List[SomeEntity] and Array[Byte[
      // at runtime because of type erasure :(
      // How to solve this?
      case s: java.util.List[java.lang.String] => {
        println(s"Found list of strings in ${m.getName}, the values are ${s.toList}")
      }
      case s: java.util.List[SubEntity] => {
        println(s"Found list of SubEntity in ${m.getName}")
      }

      case _  => println(s"Unknown ${m.getName}")
  })
```

Depending of which block I comment out, it prints

```
 Found list of strings
```

or

```
 Found list of SubEntity
```

for both fields simultaneously and is not able to correctly determine that `getField1` returns `List[SubEntity]` and `getField2` returns `List[java.lang.String]`.

How do I fix the problem and make the match work as needed?

Comment: You will need to provide the additional metadata somewhere else. Type erasure means the type information is not available by inspection. Period.

Comment: @BobDalgleish  I just found one hopeful article that suggests that it might be possible in some cases; I'm already fiddling with the Generic Method Return Types example. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html#returntypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to do it myself, with help of the article here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html#returntypes

I created a helper method for checking the return type generics and verifying if it contains the requested argument:

```
  import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

  def doesMethodReturnGenericSubtype(objectClass: Class[_], methodName: String,
                                      typeClassToCheck: Class[_]) = {

    val method = objectClass.getMethod(methodName)
    val returnType = method.getGenericReturnType

    // assume no type known
    var typeFound = false

    if (returnType.isInstanceOf[ParameterizedType]) {
      val pType = returnType.asInstanceOf[ParameterizedType]
      val typeArguments = pType.getActualTypeArguments
      for (typeArgument <- typeArguments) {
        val typeArgClass = typeArgument.asInstanceOf[Class[_]]
        if (typeArgClass.getName == typeClassToCheck.getName)
          typeFound = true
      }
    }

    typeFound
  }
```

Using it like this:

```
  val ent = new Entity
  ent.getClass.getMethods
    .filter (m => m.getName.startsWith("get") && m.getName != "getClass")
    .filter (m => m.getParameterTypes.size == 0)
    .foreach (m => m.invoke(ent) match {
      case null => null

      case s: java.util.Collection[_] if doesMethodReturnGenericSubtype(ent.getClass,
        m.getName, classOf[java.lang.String]) => {

        println(s"Found list of strings in ${m.getName}, the values are ${s.toList}")
      }

      case s: java.util.Collection[_] if doesMethodReturnGenericSubtype(ent.getClass,
        m.getName, classOf[SubEntity]) => {

        println(s"Found list of SubEntity in ${m.getName}")
      }

      case x  => println(s"Unknown ${m.getName} in ${x.getClass.getName}")
  })
```

I'm still not sure how `getActualTypeArguments` is able to extract the generic type if it has been "erased", but somehow it works just fine.